# Showing and hiding a Gtk.TextView

Tags: textview, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

i've a problem on showing and hiding a Gtk.TextView. The UI is drawed by Glade,
here below the code:

```
self.__Indirizzi_IP_TextView = builder.get_object('Indirizzi_IP_TextView')
self.__Indirizzi_IP_Window = builder.get_object('Indirizzi_IP_Window')

self.__Indirizzi_IP_Window.connect("delete-event", lambda widget, args=(): widget.hide())
```

Here below the signal handler for the clicked-event of the right Gtk.Button

```
def Visualizza_indirizzi_IP_Button_clicked(self, widget, args=()):

        textbuffer = self.__Indirizzi_IP_TextView.get_buffer()
        textbuffer.set_text((' ').join(self.__configurazione['Indirizzi_IP']))
        self.__Indirizzi_IP_Window.show()
```

Every time i try to show it:

- the first time it works correctly, the window appears with the data
- then i close it, and if i try to re-open i got a blank window

I don't know what to do, because this code comes from the [official tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/textview.html?highlight=textview#the-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: You use `widget.hide()` as the `delete-event` handler, but that does not stop other handlers from running as hide() does not return True. As a result the window gets deleted. Try writing your own handler that calls hide() and returns True.

Comment: Thank you! I always forget, False for delete-event, True for destroy-event